# how to update the count of objects in another column of a table in hibernate in many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

i have 2 tables **Offers**,**Stores**, both are mapped with **Many-to-Many** Association(**Offer_Store_mapping** table). Now i would like to **update** the **no.of offers** in a store periodically(i.e **count no.of offers in store and update the number in** total_offers **column of store table**.).  I tried in many ways, but could not get it. please help me to do this.

UPDATE: i have to count only active offer(skip expired ones.)

Thanks
raju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd always use a query for this task.

A separated column is going to denormalize your table schema and you'd need a database trigger to update the counter whenever you add/remove new orders.

Since you only need to count all offers for a particular store, the query can use an [index-only scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) because it only needs to use the store_id FK, which should always be indexed anyway.

Comment: @ **Vlad Mihalcea** thanks for your reply. I have **one more Question** for u. This time i have a complex calculation in query which is not suppose to be calculated every time when user requested. i must calculate and update in  respective column. **How to update a column in the same table where we need to calculation with other columns** Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use a database trigger to update some column whenever an order is inserted/deleted. This way you can move the calculation to the DML operation, slowing down the write while speeding up the reads. If the calculation is very expensive and the writes would take too long, then you can use a separate batch processor to update a persistent cache where you store these values. But this last option breaks consistency, since there will be a time interval between the DB change and the cache update. So you need to balance these options and see which one fits better.